# Top N by Total Sales in Year X Filter Tableau

Tags: filter, tableau-api, top-n

How to place a filter in my worksheet that filters a category by top sales in a certain year while still showing all years of data for that category.

Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to create a calculated field called **Sales_In_Selected_Year** that returns the sales for the year you care about and null otherwise such as:

```
if Year = Selected_Year then Sales end
```

Place **Sales_In_Selected_Year** on the filter shelf wth a Top filter and use the original Sales field as desired. Selected_Year can be a parameter for flexibility.